# JPA query after save doesn't return database generated field

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to save this model to a database, and then retrieve what I just saved.  Every field is retrieved except for the database generated UUID field.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usertoken")
public class UserToken implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "token", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID token;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="usersid", nullable=false)
    private User user;
    
    @Column(name = "expiration", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime expiration;
```

I save the token from within the service

```
token = tokenRepository.save(token);
```

which generates this SQL

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        usertoken
        (expiration, usersid) 
    values
        (?, ?)
```

The next statement gets the token

```
token = tokenRepository.findByUser(user);
```

I see the SQL select includes the token field

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        usertoken0_.id as id1_8_,
        usertoken0_.expiration as expirati2_8_,
        usertoken0_.token as token3_8_,
        usertoken0_.usersid as usersid4_8_ 
    from
        usertoken usertoken0_ 
    where
        usertoken0_.usersid=?
```

...but the returned object has every field populated BUT the token.  The database does have a value in the token column.
I'm at a loss as to why it would populate every field but one.
Here's the table in question:

```
CREATE TABLE public.usertoken
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    usersid integer NOT NULL,
    token uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1(),
    expiration timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "usertoken_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I forgot to add that when I query later on the token is found and the UUID field is properly populated.  So something weird with JPA caching?  Are database DEFAULT column values ignored by hibernate after the insert?

```
tokenRepository.findByToken(UUID.fromString(userToken));

Hibernate: 
    select
        usertoken0_.id as id1_8_,
        usertoken0_.expiration as expirati2_8_,
        usertoken0_.token as token3_8_,
        usertoken0_.usersid as usersid4_8_ 
    from
        usertoken usertoken0_ 
    where
        usertoken0_.token=?
```

Comment: Maybe data for `UUID` type not properly serialized, you can try with string type

Comment: I updated my original post to state that I can get a value back, just not immediately after saving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You have to signal hibernate that field is being generated by database. So add the following:

```
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Generated(value = GenerationTime.INSERT)
    @Column(name = "token", insertable = false, 
            updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID token;
```

- You will also see hibernate issues a `select` just for that column after `insert`

Comment: That did it.  Now is there a way to indicate this via a JPA annotation or only hibernate?

Comment: There is no JPA annotation. you will have to use the above hibernate annotation

Comment: Really new thing to learn! Does that mean saveAndFlush should also work?

Comment: @Eklavya I am not actually sure about `saveAndFlush()`, because it's purpose is to flush what is so far queued in the session in uncommited state so the next query in the same transaction sees it. Here the purpose is opposite as something else changed the database while the transaction is in progress which hibernate is not aware of. So I suspect even if I do `saveFlush` , there is no reason for hibernate to issue a select for that column before the `saveFlush` method returns

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai My thinking is saveAndFlush() the data and again get fetch the data using query in same transaction as OP doing, then may be get the data feached from database.

Comment: Problem is when the results comeback, hibernate will probably ignore anything that has the same id as from the previous save saying `hey i know this object, i have it in my session, I don't need to populate it again`. `saveAndFlush` is more to help with a table level query incase the one in session satisfies that query too. But when the results comeback, hibernate will only create the objects that it does not have yet in session.  But I would play with this and confirm you.